# How to change the dimension of a tile dynamically in gridview in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, gridview

i'm trying to build an app with flutter to play nonogram. I'm building the game screen and i want the hints for the game to be in the appropriate column or row. I was able to build the part of the grid that changes on tap but i don't know how to build the tiles to write the hints: i want the blue tiles (https://i.stack.imgur.com/cu3L3.png) to expand vertically (columns) or horizontally (rows) to fit the hints but i'm not able to do that. I don't even know if it's the right way to do this but i found that it was better to keep the rows and the columns aligned. Is there a way to achieve what i want? Basically i want the screen to look more or less like this (https://i.stack.imgur.com/1lbVn.png). The code i wrote so far is this:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyHomePage2 extends StatefulWidget {
  final int difficulty;
  const MyHomePage2({super.key, required this.difficulty});
  @override
  State<MyHomePage2> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage2> {
  late List<int> _list;
  bool enable = true;
  int totalLines = 0;

  final MaterialStateProperty<Icon?> thumbIcon =
      MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith<Icon?>(
    (Set<MaterialState> states) {
      // Thumb icon when the switch is selected.
      if (states.contains(MaterialState.selected)) {
        return null;
      }
      return const Icon(Icons.close);
    },
  );

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    totalLines = (widget.difficulty / 5 + 6).round();
    _list = List.generate(widget.difficulty + totalLines, (index) => 0);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('sudoku'),
          backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
        ),
        body: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            Flexible(
              flex: 2,
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: GridView.builder(
                    gridDelegate:
                        const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                            crossAxisCount: 6),
                    itemCount: widget.difficulty + totalLines,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return Container(
                        margin: index % 6 == 0 || index / 6.0 < 1
                            ? const EdgeInsets.only(
                                bottom: 2, right: 2, left: 2)
                            : const EdgeInsets.all(0),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                            borderRadius: index % 6 == 0 || index / 6.0 < 1
                                ? const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5))
                                : null,
                            border: index == 0
                                ? null
                                : index % 6 == 0 || index / 6.0 < 1
                                    ? Border.all(color: Colors.blue, width: 1)
                                    : Border.all(
                                        color: Colors.black, width: 1)),
                        child: ListTile(
                          contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
                          title: index % 6 == 0 || index / 6.0 < 1
                              ? const Text("") //Hints
                              : _list.elementAt(index) == 2
                                  ? const Icon(Icons.close_rounded, size: 50)
                                  : null,
                          tileColor: index % 6 == 0 || index / 6.0 < 1
                              ? null
                              : _list.elementAt(index) == 0
                                  ? Colors.white
                                  : _list.elementAt(index) == 1
                                      ? Colors.blueGrey[800]
                                      : Colors.transparent,
                          onTap: () {
                            if (enable) {
                              if (_list.elementAt(index) == 0 ||
                                  _list.elementAt(index) == 2) {
                                setState(() {
                                  _list[index] = 1;
                                });
                              } else {
                                setState(() {
                                  _list[index] = 0;
                                });
                              }
                            } else {
                              if (_list.elementAt(index) == 2) {
                                setState(() {
                                  _list[index] = 0;
                                });
                              } else if (_list.elementAt(index) == 0 ||
                                  _list.elementAt(index) == 1) {
                                setState(() {
                                  _list[index] = 2;
                                });
                              }
                            }
                          },
                        ),
                      );
                    }),
              ),
            ),
            Flexible(
              //flex: 1,
              child: Transform.scale(
                scale: 2.0,
                child: Switch(
                  activeColor: Colors.black,
                  thumbIcon: thumbIcon,
                  value: enable,
                  onChanged: (bool value) {
                    setState(() {
                      enable = value;
                    });
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ));
  }
}
```

I tried wrapping everything with the expanded widget but it doesn't work properly. I tried to find a way to change the aspect ratio dynamically but i didn't managed to do it

Comment: try `CustomMultiChildLayout` - the docs say: "CustomMultiChildLayout is appropriate when there are complex relationships between the size and positioning of multiple widgets", you can check https://stackoverflow.com/a/70982400/2252830 for some hints